# How can I edit the shadow and style of an item that is being reordered in a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

So I am new to Swift and SwiftUI, and I'm trying to create a list that can be reordered. I could achieve this, but the thing is that the effect shown below is really annoying and I can't get rid of it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[List reordering effect shown in a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puA7K.gif)

EDIT2: The effect I'm talking about is the shadow and black borders that appear on the selected item that is being dragged.

EDIT: This is my code now

```
            GeometryReader { reader in
                List {
                    ForEach(model.farmList, id: \.id) { farm in
                        buildRow(name: "Farm name")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                # does something
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 16, bottom: 4, trailing: 16))
                            .frame(
                                minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
                                minHeight: 76,
                                alignment: .leading
                            )
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: move)
                }
                .environment(\.editMode, model.isEditable ? .constant(.active) : .constant(.inactive))
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve and show your existing code? You want to be able to reorder items without being able to delete them, is this it?

Comment: Hi! What I want to achieve is that when I drag an item I do not want to see that shadow and black borders that appear on the selected row. I don't know if that's possible